# Noun for borrow

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns

A customer borrows a book from a library. The library stores all of these "actions" in a database. What will be a single entry in that database called?

Comment: *Borrowings*...

Comment: An **event**? There will be several kinds of event, from withdrawing or returning a book, to being issued a reminder or a fine for late return.

Comment: In this context, it's usually 'withdrawals'. This is certainly not an ELU question; I don't expect a piggyback 'answer'.

Comment: A "loan", perhaps?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what to name software artifacts is specifically off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Robusto What I had in mind (as stated in a title of a question) was a noun for "borrow" but in a context you would use in a library. I've put the example with database for a context. You would have no idea what I was talking about without that context

Comment: @Robusto feel free to edit the question to better describe the problem, but as a non-English speaker that was what I came up with

Comment: Well, what's your motivation for asking the question? I'm assuming that your motivation is not naming a database table (which would be off topic for this site), so presumably you can just describe your actual motivation.